# call external .js file in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `array.js` file and an `index.html`.

My `array.js` file looks like this:

```
function go(){
    var array = new Array();
    array[0] = "Red";
    array[1] = "Blue";
    array[3] = "Green";
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
        document.write("<li>" + array[i] + "<br />");
    }
}
```

My `index.html` file looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="array.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="go()" value="Display JS Array"/>
        <script>
            go();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click the `Display JS Array` button on the HTML page, nothing happens.
I want the array elements to be displayed after I click the button.
It should look like:

- Red
- Blue
- Green

Comment: Which browser are you working on where nothing happens ? Most probably your script `array.js` is not at root location where you are trying to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace this `document.write("<li>" + array[i] + "<br />");` with `document.write("<li>" + array[i] + "</li>");`

and in your HTML file, remove

```
<script>
  go();
</script>
```

because already you calling go(); function on onclick. and in your array, array[2] will give undefined.

try this its working for me :

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function go(){
                var array = new Array();
                array[0] = "Red";
                array[1] = "Blue";
                array[2] = "Green";
                li = document.getElementById("list");
                li_arr = "";
                for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
                   li_arr += "<li>" + array[i] + "</li>";
                }
               li.innerHTML = li_arr;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="go()" value="Display JS Array"/>
        <ul id="list"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: array[3] should be array[2]. that was a typo.

Comment: I tried what you suggest, and it makes sense that that would work. However, I am still getting the same problem. When I click the button nothing happens.  Is there anything else I could be neglecting? This should work.

Comment: Hi thanks. I got that to work and got it working from external .js file too.   One other thing, when i click the button it shows the results in a new blank page.  How do i get it do display where the button is? I have other stuff on the page that still needs to be vidible after I click the button.  I messed around with a div, but no luck. Thanks

Comment: if you use document.write, it will clear everything and writes to document, you can create empty ul and append it to that instead of document.write.

Comment: In the HTML file I added <ul id="colors"></ul> below the button.

Comment: Then, in the JS file, I changed to:                      var col = "";
                for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
                 col+= "<li>" + array[i] + </"li">;
                }
                document.getElementById("colors").innerHTML = col;
            }

Comment: This is not working though. Please help.  Could this be done using jquery? that might be faster.  Thanks

Comment: @zmny check my answer now, i edited it. venilla javascript perform more faster than jquery.

Comment: Thanks Shreedhar!  How do I get the array to print out inside a table on the index.html page? I tried adding the table html tags both around the button and seperately also in the .js file, but the array contents is printing above the table and only the bottom part of the table border is appearing.

Comment: I figured it out. thanks.  Just appended the html table tags inside the loop: li_arr += "<tr>"+"<td>" + "<li>" + array[i] + "</li>" + "</td>"+"</tr>";  and to the li.innerHTML variable inside the .js file:  li.innerHTML = "<table border=1>" + "<th>Title</th>" + li_arr + "</table>";

Answer (score 4):

You can change the function by taking the parent element of li elements as parameter.

```
function go(element){
    var array = new Array();
    array[0] = "Red";
    array[1] = "Blue";
    array[3] = "Green";

    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
       var li = document.createElement("li");
       li.innerHtml = array[i];
       ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    body.insertAfter(ul, element); 
}


<input type="button" onclick="go(this)" value="Display JS Array"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is quite ok. And working fine. Yes you can use external JS or internal JS .

**By using External JS:** -

**Test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="arrayy.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="go()" value="Display JS Array"/>       
    </body>
</html>
```

**arrayy.js**

```
function go(){
    var array = new Array();
    array[0] = "Red";
    array[1] = "Blue";
    array[3] = "Green";
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
        document.write("<li>" + array[i] + "<br />");
    }
}
```

These above codes are running in Mozilla Firefox ,IE 8 and some other browser.

**By Using Internal JS:** -

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function go(){
            var array = new Array();
            array[0] = "Red";
            array[1] = "Blue";
            array[3] = "Green";
            for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
                document.write("<li>" + array[i] + "<br />");
            }
            }        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="go()" value="Display JS Array"/>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine for me.

But as shreedhar said:
You need to delete

```
 <script>
 go();
 </script>
```

this otherwise it will be displayed before you pressed the button. 
An since array[2] is undefined you need to filter that one from your array.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you are using jquery dom ready function then make the modification on arrayy.js like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    this.go = function(){
        var array = new Array();
        array[0] = "Red";
        array[1] = "Blue";
        array[3] = "Green";
        for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
           document.write("<li>" + array[i] + "<br />");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: avoid using key words as the file name like "array.js" where array is the keyword.