# Separate HTML / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to have my JavaScript code in a file apart from my HTML file.

Linking the 2 scripts between each other works, however stuff like the function `document.getElementById()` doesn't.

**Anyone know how to fix this?**

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>   
        <head>
            <title>Boost</title>
            <script src="javascript.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>
                <p id="TopTextParagraph">Hi there</p>
                <div>
                    <button id="clickNext">Next</button>
                </div>
            </h3>
        </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("clickNext").onclick = goNext;

function goNext() { 
    console.log("stuff here")
}
```

JavaScript works when I put it in the HTML file using `<script> </script>`, just don't know how to make it work in a separate JavaScript file.

Comment: We might, had we seen some of your code. As it is now, no. Edit your question, click the `<>` and add html and script

Comment: I've added my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840148/call-external-js-file-in-html

Comment: Either move the script to the end of the page or wrap in `window.onload=function() {...}` so the element exists when you try to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the script inside `head` tag. When that snippet is executed `clickNext` element does not exist in the dom

You can add the script near the closing body tag to resolve the problem & remove from the head tag

```
<body>
  <h3>
<p id="TopTextParagraph"> Hi there</p>
<div>< button id="clickNext"> Next</button></div>
</h3>
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```